# webdriver freezes after chrome page timeout

Tags: selenium, webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I have a page that takes some time to load (30-60 seconds), so I have setup an implicit wait, and would like to be able to refresh the page if it doesn't finish loading the first time.

My code does not end up refreshing the page in Chrome (the loading spinner doesn't start and the page doesn't change), nor does it print out the status of the Javascript call - I don't know why.  I'm running Chrome 68, with chromedriver 2.42 and Python 3.6.

I've replaced the actual URL and timeout with sample values below to make it reproducible:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
import os

mypath = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
chrome_path = mypath+"/chromedriver"

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=chrome_path)
driver.set_page_load_timeout(2)

try:
    driver.get("https://www.bbcnews.com")
except TimeoutException:
    print("Timeout, retrying...")
    state = driver.execute_script("var state = document.readyState; return state;")
    print(state)
    driver.refresh("https://www.bbcnews.com")
```